# Keras fit method giving expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (196, 353, 1)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm using the following Keras model:

```
    # Create Model
    self.model = Sequential()
    self.model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(features_set.shape[1], features_set.shape[2])))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    self.model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    self.model.add(LSTM(50))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    self.model.add(Dense(1))
    self.model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
```

The `features_set.shape` is `196,353,4`, and the `labels.shape` is `196,353,1`.

However when this is called right after:

```
    self.model.fit(features_set, labels, epochs = 1, batch_size = 1)
    self.model.reset_states()
```

I get the error:

> expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (196, 353, 1)

The last LSTM is not returning the sequences, so what is going on here? I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrong model building, dense output is (196, 1), you are fitting labels.shape (196,353,1)

try this

```
# Create Model
    self.model = Sequential()
    self.model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(features_set.shape[1], features_set.shape[2])))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    self.model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    self.model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    self.model.add(Dense(1))
    self.model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
```

Comment: Thank you, I feel like an idiot. I'm confused, I thought Dense was never supposed to get the sequences so the last LSTM was not supposed to return it?